# Why are all my sinks draining slowly?

Tags: plumbing, water, sink

I have a problem with water flowing out in several places slowly, so that in the sinks affected it flows out slowly (slow enough that the running water fills up the sink more and more).

I checked a few of the siphons/traps and they are not clogged. I've also put a snake down down the kitchen pipe to check for problems around the next corners, but it came back clean (length about 5m).

The problem occurs in all of the sinks (bathroom, toilet and kitchen) **downstairs**, but the toilets themselves as well as the showers seem unaffected, as are the **upstairs** sinks, which baffles me.

What could the problem be and how can I figure out what is going on?

---

additional information to questions asked:

- House is about 5 years old.
- Has a basement where I unfortunately couldn't find anything (a big pipe coming down, continuing horizontally and outwards, this is most likely the main outgoing, no valves or vents or cleanout that I could find).
- No trees at the house or nearby where the water main runs.
- Building is in continental Europe, cold climate in winter (Austria).

---

This might be related to my previous issue:
[Water going out badly from sinks and shower - how to locate the issue?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/113566/water-going-out-badly-from-sinks-and-shower-how-to-locate-the-issue)

However, since different items are affected this time (the showers not, but some sinks that were fine before now are backing up) I'm asking a new question as the issues may or may not be related.-

Comment: Siphons? Did you mean traps? Please re-read your first paragraph and revise it. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: This sounds like a slow main line if first floor sinks are mostly effected.  Do you have a basement?   How old is the house or outdoor sewer line? Are there trees along the sewer line?

Comment: @Tyson answers added to question.

Comment: Seems to me the main drainpipe leaving the house is NOT the problem since some of the house drains fine. It appears your downstairs fixtures share a "downstairs main" drainpipe that in turn feeds the "whole-house" (main) drainpipe that runs outside.  This "downstairs main" seemingly has the clog.  Can you locate the downstairs fixture for which its drainpipe is the closest to where the "downstairs main" drainpipe feeds into the whole-house main drainpipe?  I suspect a clog there (it's possible you have more than one clog).  Can you snake that fixture?  Others (downstairs)?

Comment: Slow drainage. You've tried a plunger with all that lovely water waiting to flow down your sinks? Sometimes plunger works better than snake, especially if you can get water (non-compressible)  backed up all the way from clog to sink drain. A little soap in the water makes hairballs etc. slipperier.

Comment: Thanks so far. I'm trying to find the clog, will snake another drain the next days. So far no luck.

Comment: I know it's an ancient question now, but the problem appears again from time to time, so I'm still waiting for an answer. @WayfaringStranger yes, plunging seems to work best and when done to intensity (like half an hour, not the 10 or so pumps that some websites speak of) it does clean it up - for anywhere between a few days and a few weeks. Water coming up is quite milky with small particles of something white and, of course, general dirt.